# My SSD can't be selected from Windows 7 install menu

Tags: windows-7, installation, ssd

I can't choose my SSD when I try to install Windows. Only my secondary HDD allowed. SATA mode selection in UEFI BIOS is set to AHCI.

Can I check somewhere check if my SSD is working correctly? Type of SSD is Kingston SSD NOW V300.

Comment: does it show up? what does BIOS show?

Comment: I dont know where to find if SDD is instaled in UEFI bios... Sorry. I let my PC assamble from IT company.

Comment: What is the make and model of your motherboard?

Comment: GIGABYTE GA-Z77-D3H - Intel Z77

Comment: If you look at the picture above the text "The BIOS Features panel has settings to configure the boot drive priority," on [KitGuru GA-Z77-D3H review](http://www.kitguru.net/components/motherboard/zardon/gigabyte-ga-z77-d3h-motherboard-packs-a-punch-at-80/4/), you can see that the disk drives should be listed in the "BIOS Features"->"Boot Option Priorities" section.

Comment: Disk is not listed is section you mention above.

Comment: In that case, it appears that either the SSD is not connected (one of its cables could have come loose in transit), its SATA cable is faulty, or the SSD itself is faulty. If you are not comfortable opening up the computer and checking the cables are connected properly (just unplugging and replugging them with the computer disconnected from the mains might fix it), then I suggest you contact the IT company which assembled the computer for you. P.S. If you put @AndrewMorton at the start of a reply, I will be notified.

Answer (score 1):

If your SSD does not show up when installing Windows, you need to download the proper drivers for your SATA controller most likely and load them during Windows setup.

Comment: I already tried that I dowloaded V300_525w_Win.exe extrect it to USB disk and where I try to browse it I get error msg: No signed device drivers were found...

Comment: @user306384 It is unlikely that Windows 7 does not have the drivers for your storage controller.

Comment: It seems unlikely also to me, but these drivers comes from official Kingston webside. Dont know what I am doing wrong...

Comment: The driver you would want is [Intel SATA Preinstall driver](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4720#dl) (scroll down to the "SATA RAID/AHCI" section). However, Windows 7 will have a sufficient driver already.

Answer (score 0):

Check the SATA cable connection to the SSD, or try a different cable.
try a different installer to see if something else can at least pick it up.

Give a Linux installer a go, boot into the live mode and start the install process, check it can pick up the SSD.

Try to narrow down where the problem is. Is it the connection/cable. your windows 7 installer or maybe a broken SSD.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this recently.

First, you need to check if the BIOS/UEFI is recognizing the SSD. Normally you would do this by pressing F8 (or DEL on certain motherboards) as the PC is turning on and you see the motherboard manufacturer logo. This brings you into the UEFI/BIOS menu where you should look for something along the lines of boot devices/hard disks. Again, this depends on your motherboard manufacturer. You may need to look into the manual for your motherboard. If you can find your SSD listed in the UEFI/BIOS, then you can move to my second point (below). If it does not show up in the UEFI/BIOS, then you have a SATA cable connection problem, a power problem or a genuine busted SSD. You need to double-check the hard disk cable connections inside the computer.

Second, if your SSD is recognized in UEFI/BIOS but it does not show up when you insert the Windows install disk, you should try unplugging the other hard disks in your computer leaving only the SSD attached. This is the solution that fixed it for me.

Third, if my second point works for you and you manage to install Windows, you need to plug your other hard disks back in. However, you may run into a problem where in Windows Explorer only your SSD shows up - this can be solved by going into `Disk Management` and importing the foreign disks.